# How to separate string and number in Python list?

Tags: python

I have a list as below.

```
list = ['perfect','data1', 'queryda873', 'server187', 'tuplip91', 'time']
```

How can I separate tokens and numbers in the list? I want something like:

```
list = ['perfect','data', '1', 'queryda','873', 'server','187', 'tulip','91', 'time']
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you do about one2three? one, 2, three?

Comment: I am trying to use "match = re.match(r"(....([0-9]+..)"  but have no idea.

Answer (score 10):

You can try using regular expressions ([`re`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)). In particular, `\d+|\D+`:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> L = ['perfect','data1', 'queryda873', 'server187', 'tuplip91', 'time']
>>> 
>>> [s for v in (re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', s) for s in L) for s in v]
['perfect', 'data', '1', 'queryda', '873', 'server', '187', 'tuplip', '91', 'time']
```

By the way, you shouldn't name your variables `list`, since that name is taken by a built-in function.

Comment: Good point about `list` as a name, but [Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable names.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)

Comment: @nmichaels I'd say it's not a big deal for small snippets like this, but I'll change it if you like.

Comment: Oh, I agree. I was just being pedantic.

Comment: That's great, but good lord is that hard to read.

Comment: Thanks. I have quick question. If I want put this into 3 lines I don't know why I cannot print out the list. 
for v in (re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', s) for s in myList):
        for s in v:
            print myList=mylist.append(s)

Comment: @theteddyboy Do all the appending first, then print at the end. There's an issue with `myList=mylist.append(s)`.

Comment: @theteddyboy `list.append` changes the list in place, and returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this already has an accepted answer, but I had to add this alternative, simply because I think it's easier to read and understand.

```
import re
import itertools

lst = ['perfect','data1', 'queryda873', 'server187', 'tuplip91', 'time']
broken = map(lambda s: re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', s), lst)
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(broken))
# merged is now ['perfect', 'data', '1', 'queryda', '873', 'server', '187', 'tuplip', '91', 'time']
```

Comment: sorry can you explain the itertools.chain.from_iterable(broken)? I tried to run but error alerts.

Comment: What error did you get, and what version of python are you using?

Comment: @theteddyboy `chain.from_iterable` "flattens" a nested iterable. (i.e., turns `[[1,2],[3,4]]` into `iter([1,2,3,4])`)

Comment: I have no warnings or errors with that code on 2.7.3.  I'm not sure what you're seeing, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
l = ['perfect','data1', 'queryda873', 'server187', 'tuplip91', 'time']
from itertools import groupby
[''.join(g) for x in l for k,g in groupby(x, key=lambda y: y.isdigit())]
['perfect', 'data', '1', 'queryda', '873', 'server', '187', 'tuplip', '91', 'time']
```